# How can I assign a multiple-field-function result on PostgreSQL updates

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I'm looking for an optimized method in PostgreSQL to do that:

```
update table1
set (a,b)=(somecomplexfunction(table1.something),2*somecomplexfunction(table1.something)) 
where ...
```

this calculates somecomplexfunction(table1.something) twice, I'd like to do something like that:

```
update table1 set (a,b)=somecomplexvectorfunction(table1.something) where ...
```

but update syntax does not support multiple field functions. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
update table1
set
    a = somecomplexfunction(table1.something),
    b = a * 2
where ...
```

Comment: isn't "a" the old "a" by the time I double it?